# Font used in text, appears like code

Tags: fonts, code

Does someone has an idea of the font used in the text in the image:

[image]

Comment: `\texttt{...}`, `{\tt ...}`, or `\mono{...}`, depending on whether you are using LaTeX, Plain TeX, or ConTeXt.

Comment: And to identify the actual font see: [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/2693).

Comment: Comparing against the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html), it looks like Computer Modern Teletype